# Can I render font onto an HTML canvas at a large size, and then downsample it to fit the canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I have a small canvas:

```
<canvas id="game-canvas" width="256" height="232"></canvas>
```

I'm scaling it to fit the window with:

```
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  image-rendering: pixelated;
  background: black;
}

canvas {
  background: black;
  width: 100vh;
  margin: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

This is how I'm drawing the text on the canvas, using an external font.

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#game-canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

---

const draw = () =>
{
    // draw objects in mounted scene
    mainScene.draw(ctx, 0, 0);

    var numRupees = 0;
    var numKeys = 0;
    var numBombs = 0;

    // text 
    ctx.fillText('X' + numRupees, gridCells(13), gridCells(2.75));
    ctx.fillText('X' + numKeys, gridCells(13), gridCells(4.75));
    ctx.fillText('X' + numBombs, gridCells(13), gridCells(5.75));
    ctx.fillText("It's dangerous to go", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
    ctx.fillText("alone! Take this.", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 7.5);
};

---

const tlozFont = new FontFace('tloz', 'url(./public/fonts/the-legend-of-zelda-nes.ttf)');

tlozFont.load().then(function (font) {
    document.fonts.add(font);
    document.body.classList.add('fonts-loaded');
    console.log('Font loaded.');

    ctx.font = '8px tloz';
    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
});
```

The problem is that my canvas is rendering clearly, but the text is pixelated - because I have to use a font size of 8px to size it properly. I noticed that when I set the font size to something crazy like 1000px, it's clear - but obviously way too big to fit the canvas.

My canvas:

[image: My canvas.]

Is it possible to render the font at that larger size, and then just scale it down to fit the canvas?

I've spent days trying out every single solution I find on google, but nothing works. Either they make the canvas and font too small, or they make the font clear but the canvas blurry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anti-aliasing works by smoothing out rough edges using the intended colour at a lower alpha value. So if you draw white text, your text gets actually surrounded by white pixels at a alpha value lower than 255 - which would be fully opaque. So on a black background those pixels would look gray-ish.

With this in mind here's a little workaround:

Instead of drawing the text directly onto your target canvas, paint it onto a second canvas first. Now loop over all the pixels and check if the alpha values fall below a certain threshold - say 170. If that happens turn that pixel off by setting the red, green, blue and alpha values to zero. If finished paint the result on your target canvas.

Here's what it looks like with and without this technique:

[image]

and here's the code:

```
const canvas = document.querySelector('#game-canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
const textCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
textCanvas.width = canvas.width;
textCanvas.height = canvas.height;
const textContext = textCanvas.getContext("2d");

const draw = () => {
    renderText("It's dangerous to go", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 15);
    renderText("alone! Take this.", canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2 - 7.5);

};

const renderText = (text, x, y) => {
    textContext.clearRect(0, 0, textCanvas.width, textCanvas.height);
    textContext.fillText(text, x, y);

    let imageData = textContext.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    let data = imageData.data;
    for (let a = 0; a < data.length; a += 4) {
        if (data[a + 3] < 170) {
            data[a] = 0;
            data[a + 1] = 0;
            data[a + 2] = 0;
            data[a + 3] = 0;
        }
    }
    textContext.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(textCanvas, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}



const tlozFont = new FontFace('tloz', 'url(./public/fonts/the-legend-of-zelda-nes.ttf)');

tlozFont.load().then(function(font) {
    document.fonts.add(font);
    document.body.classList.add('fonts-loaded');
    console.log('Font loaded.');

    textContext.font = '8px tloz';
    textContext.textAlign = 'center';
    textContext.fillStyle = 'white';
    draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can but it's not worth it. Scaling a large font down to occupy the same canvas pixels that 8px font size text would occupy if written directly to the smaller canvas can't be expected to improve appearance. Canvas elements are *pixelated*.

You may want to check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/image-rendering for upscaling the canvas using different methods, or use a larger canvas to start with and down-scale it to fit smaller view ports.